# Get row-index values of Pandas DataFrame as list?

Tags: python, list, pandas, indexing

I'm probably using poor search terms when trying to find this answer. Right now, before indexing a DataFrame, I'm getting a list of values in a column this way...

```
 list = list(df['column'])
```

...then I'll `set_index` on the column. This seems like a wasted step. When trying the above on an index, I get a key error.

How can I grab the values in an index (both single and multi) and put them in a list or a list of tuples?

Comment: *Why* do you want them as a list??

Comment: If you're only getting these to manually pass into `df.set_index()`, that's unnecessary. Just directly do `df.set_index['your_col_name', drop=False]`, already.

Comment: As for _why_... I personally need to get the index values of a dataframe as a list during debugging (Evaluate Expression in PyCharm) or double-checking between steps when programming interactively (for example, in a Jupyter notebook) all the time.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

To get the `index` values as a `list`/`list` of `tuple`s for `Index`/`MultiIndex` do:

```
df.index.values.tolist()  # an ndarray method, you probably shouldn't depend on this
```

or

```
list(df.index.values)  # this will always work in pandas
```

Comment: I get TypeError: 'list' object is not callable for using `list(df.index.values)`

Comment: @Bode you probably have another variable called `list` in scope.

Comment: `df.index.tolist()` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only getting these to manually pass into `df.set_index()`, that's unnecessary. **Just directly do `df.set_index['your_col_name', drop=False]`**, already.

It's very rare in pandas that you need to get an index as a Python list (unless you're doing something pretty funky, or else passing them back to NumPy), so if you're doing this a lot, it's a code smell that you're doing something wrong.